# Page chaining in POM method

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, pom

I have created three packages.

- generic
- webpage
- script

In **generic** I have base test and other common methods.
In **webpage** I created class for each web page.
In **Script** I have my testcases.

I need to execute my all the script through `testng.xml` and run only once login and logout functionality of application.

When I used `@BeforeSuite` and `@AfterSuite` to open and close the browser; I'm getting null pointer execption.

> How can I run all the test cases in a single login and logout attempt?

Comment: You should provide us the code.

Comment: We will need the code and the exception to have any idea what is happening. A null pointer exception means that you are calling an object that does not exist in that code scope

Answer (score 0):

To run all the test cases in a single login and logout,create a separate class which contains your @BeforeSuite(login testcase) and @AfterSuite(logout testcase).Then extend this class in your main class where all your test scripts are present.By this way you can run all your test cases in a single login and logout.